# Custom error message using CodeIgniter Form Validation

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, validation

I want to make some custom error messages in my CodeIgniter forms. I've tried using

`$this->form_validation->set_message('is_unique[users.username]', 'The username is already taken');`

However I can't get it working.

Editing the `form_validation_lang.php` file is not good enough, as `is_unique` will be **The username is already taken** for usernames, and **The e-mail is already registered** for mails.

How can I make this custom error message?

Here's a snippet from my code:

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('is_unique[users.username]', 'The username is already taken');

// Check if username has changed
if ($this->input->post('username') !== $user->username) {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|min_length[4]|max_length[20]|is_unique[users.username]');
}
```

Comment: check out the form validation example on the codeigniter documentation site.. http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks

Comment: The code example I posted is identical to the docs: `$this->form_validation->set_message('required', 'Your custom message here');
`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Right way of doing this is by passing a string format

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('is_unique', 'The %s is already taken');
```

So, then only we can able to get message like `"This Username is already taken"` or `"This Email is already taken"`.

Comment: What if i want to replace the '%s' with the actual input value? Ex. 'Foo' is already taken...

Answer (score 6):

This is how you set a message error ONLY for username:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','is_unique',array('is_unique' => 'The %s is already taken'));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
create a **form_validation.php** file and use this method:

"add_user_rule"   => [
    [
        "field" => "username",
        "label" => "Username",
        "rules" => "required|trim|is_unique[users.username]",
        "errors" => [
            'is_unique' => 'The %s is already taken.',
        ],
    ],
],

Thank You
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('is_unique', 'The username is already taken');
```

Answer (score 2):

It's better you use like this:

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('is_unique', 'The %s is already taken');
```

The form_validation changes `%s` with the label seted for the field.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

you can add your custom message to `validation_errors()` string after checking validation using `$this->form_validation->run() == true`

```
if(YOUR_CONDITION){
   $this->form_validation->run();
   $err = validation_errors();
   $err = $err. '<p>Custom validation error message</p>'. PHP_EOL;
   $data['err'] = $err;
   $this->load->view('viewname', $data);
}
else if ($this->form_validation->run() == true ) {
        #code...
}
else..
```

after setting your custom message to `$err` variable, print it on your view.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the third parameter to set messages for the validation

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules(
        'username', 'Username',
        'required|min_length[5]|max_length[12]|is_unique[users.username]',
        array(
                'required'      => 'You have not provided %s.',
                'is_unique'     => 'This %s already exists.'
        )
);
```

[Check here](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#cascading-rules)

Answer (score 0):

This is example of CI4 of [custom error](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/validation.html?highlight=s#setting-custom-error-messages) and replace value and field according input.

```
$validation->setRules([
    'username' => [
        'label'  => 'Username',
        'rules'  => 'required|max_length[30]|is_unique[users.username]',
        'errors' => [
            'required' => 'All accounts must have {field} provided',
        ],
    ],
    'password' => [
        'label'  => 'Password',
        'rules'  => 'required|max_length[255]|min_length[10]',
        'errors' => [
            'min_length' => 'Your {field} is too short. You want to get hacked?',
        ],
    ],
]);
```